# Why is 'rblabla' a valid csv file mode?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file and a function to read it.

I can open it in many ways, most of these modes produce similar results.

```
def read(mode):
    with open("file.csv", mode) as inf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        for row in reader:
            print row

read('r')       #prints \r\n characters
read('rb')      #prints \r\n characters
read('rU')      #prints \n characters but not \r characters
read('rblabla') #WAT.
```

I am wondering why the last example is allowed. It produces the same results as normal read mode.

Is there any reason why it works this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mode` is not for the csv reader, but for the python default file handler. Python only enforces mode to begin with 'r', 'w' or 'a', after stripping `U`. This is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), and is for python 2.5 and later.

The mode is an attribute of the file handler, and may be used by other applications, hence it may contain more characters.